# Rust Generics with Default Trait Implementations

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm working on a Rust project where I have defined several traits (A1, A2, and A3) with multiple implementations for each trait. I also have a struct Algo that takes generics based on these traits. I want to provide default trait implementations for the generics in case no specific implementation is provided by the user.

Here's my code:

```
pub trait A1 {
    fn test1();
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Ex1_A1;

impl A1 for Ex1_A1 {
    fn test1() {
        println!("Ex1_A1");
    }
}

pub struct Ex2_A1;
impl A1 for Ex2_A1 {
    fn test1() {
        println!("Ex2_A1");
    }
}

pub trait A2 {
    fn test2();
}

pub struct Ex1_A2;
impl A2 for Ex1_A2 {
    fn test2() {
        println!("Ex1_A2");
    }
}

pub trait A3 {
    fn test3();
}

pub struct Ex1_A3;
impl A3 for Ex1_A3 {
    fn test3() {
        println!("Ex1_A3");
    }
}

struct Algo<B: A1, S: A2, M: A3> {
    a1: B,
    a2: S,
    a3: M
} 

impl <B: A1, S: A2, M: A3> Algo<B, S, M> {
    pub fn new(bbs: Option<B>, su: Option<S>, mac: Option<M>) -> Self {
        let bbs = bbs.unwrap_or(Ex1_A1);
        let su = su.unwrap_or(Ex1_A2);
        let mac = mac.unwrap_or(Ex1_A3);
        Self {
            a1: bbs,
            a2: su,
            a3: mac,
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I provide default implementations for the generics B, S, and M in the Algo struct? I've tried using Option and unwrap_or, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'd appreciate any guidance or examples on how to handle this scenario effectively in Rust.

Thank you!

Comment: You get default values by the Default trait.
You can set default types like this: Algo<B = Ex1_A1, S =Ex2_A2, M = Ex1_A3>
The user can override if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the default doesn't mesh well with static dispatch because the generic implementation and default implementation don't have the same type, so fields of `Algo` can't be initialized with an unambiguous type.

A straightforward way to resolve that is to type-erase `Algo` fields using `dyn ...`. Although dynamic dispatch has a bad rap due to the indirection it introduces, it's really perfectly fine when used as gateway into the algorithm. For example, you can define `Algo` like this:

```
struct Algo {
    a1: Box<dyn A1>,
    a2: Box<dyn A2>,
    a3: Box<dyn A3>,
}

impl Algo {
    pub fn new(
        bbs: Option<Box<dyn A1>>,
        su: Option<Box<dyn A2>>,
        mac: Option<Box<dyn A3>>,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            a1: bbs.unwrap_or_else(|| Box::new(Ex1_A1)),
            a2: su.unwrap_or_else(|| Box::new(Ex1_A2)),
            a3: mac.unwrap_or_else(|| Box::new(Ex1_A3)),
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, your trait methods need to take `&self`:

```
pub trait A1 {
    fn test1(&self);
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Ex1_A1;

impl A1 for Ex1_A1 {
    fn test1(&self) {
        println!("Ex1_A1");
    }
}
// ...
```

Finally, `new()` is now invoked with trait objects:

```
fn main() {
    let algo2 = Algo::new(Some(Box::new(Ex1_A1)), None, None);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=62cccd929fb51f3b2c8e7bc392b5232a)

Comment: Sorry but this is now working, when i try to create an instance of Algo with new(None, None, None) it says that type annotations are needed

Comment: @Alberto Updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with one more step? I woul like to have another struct like this:

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Principal {
    //...Other attributes


    #[serde(skip_serializing)]
    alg: Algo
}

but it says this:

"the trait bound `Algo: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied"

Comment: @Alberto I think you need `#[serde(skip)]`, and implement `Default for Algo`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7182f04efc3d87244cfbcbcb1c165139)

Comment: @Alberto Did my answer help with your issue? If so, consider accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

A compile time value (the generic parameter's type) cannot depend on a runtime value (`Option`). So you cannot do that.

Comment: So, how can i achieve something similar?

Comment: @Alberto You can have a method for each default. Or you can just give up on your idea and require your users to specify the defaults. It's not that bad.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to add `Default` trait bounds to your `impl`:

```rust
impl<B, S, M> Algo<B, S, M> 
where
    B: A1 + Default,
    S: A2 + Default,
    M: A3 + Default
{
    pub fn new(bbs: Option<B>, su: Option<S>, mac: Option<M>) -> Self {
        let bbs = bbs.unwrap_or_default();
        let su = su.unwrap_or_default();
        let mac = mac.unwrap_or_default();
        Self {
            a1: bbs,
            a2: su,
            a3: mac,
        }
    }
}
```

Next step to improve code usability is to set default concrete types for your `Algo` generics:

```rust
struct Algo<B: A1 = Ex1_A1, S: A2 = Ex1_A2, M: A3 = Ex1_A3> {
    a1: B,
    a2: S,
    a3: M
}

// Now `Algo` without explicit generics definition means just `Algo<Ex1_A1, Ex1_A2, Ex1_A3>`
```

And finally it is much better to use builder pattern here:

```rust
impl Algo {
    // Actually you can simply derive `Default` for the `Algo` instead of explicitly defining `new` method
    // Writing this only for better understanding
    pub fn new() -> Self
    {
        Self {
            a1: Default::default(),
            a2: Ex1_A2,
            a3: Ex1_A3,
        }
    }
}

impl<B, S, M> Algo<B, S, M> 
where
    B: A1,
    S: A2,
    M: A3,
{
    pub fn with_a1<NEW_B: A1>(self, a1: NEW_B) -> Algo<NEW_B, S, M> {
        let Algo { a2, a3, .. } = self;
        Algo { a1, a2, a3 }
    }

    pub fn with_a2<NEW_S: A2>(self, a2: NEW_S) -> Algo<B, NEW_S, M> {
        let Algo { a1, a3, .. } = self;
        Algo { a1, a2, a3 }
    }

    pub fn with_a3<NEW_M: A3>(self, a3: NEW_M) -> Algo<B, S, NEW_M> {
        let Algo { a1, a2, .. } = self;
        Algo { a1, a2, a3 }
    }
}
```

Now you can manage construction of your `Algo` as you want:

```rust
let my_algo = Algo::new()
    .with_a1(Ex2_A1)
    .with_a3(Ex1_A3);
```

Comment: Sorry but this is now working, the compiler says "type annotations needed"

Comment: Addded some adjustments. Works fine https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86bc83c60e2a456e7c177abfd72072c5

Comment: I think this implements something different than what the OP needs. Your first snippet requires the traits implementing `A1`, `A2` and `A3` to also implement `Default` - but that's not what the OP wanted, they wanted to use _different_ implementation when the option is None, not to use a default configuration of the implementation type. Your builder pattern doesn't really work either, because `Algo::new()` returns `Algo<Ex1_A1, Ex1_A2, Ex1_A3>`, so the only thing you can ever call `with_a1()` with is `Ex2_A1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "different implementation when the option is None"?